# Boost ptree reused need to be cleared or not?

Tags: c++, boost

I have written the following code (for testing):

```
boost::property_tree::ptree ptRes;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptRes2;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptRes3;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptA;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptB;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptQ;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptZ;

boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json("../a.json", ptA);
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json("../b.json", ptB);
ptRes.put_child("ptA", ptA);
ptRes.put_child("ptB", ptB);
boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json("res.json", ptRes);

boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json("../a.json", ptQ);
ptRes2.put_child("ptA", ptQ);
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json("../b.json", ptQ);
ptRes2.put_child("ptB", ptQ);
boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json("res2q.json", ptRes2);

boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json("../a.json", ptZ);
ptRes3.put_child("ptA", ptZ);
ptZ.clear();
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json("../b.json", ptZ);
ptRes3.put_child("ptB", ptZ);
boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json("res3z.json", ptRes3);
```

but the output is the same in all the 3 cases. My problem is that I want to create a `ptree` that contains 3 other `ptree`s and I am not really sure how to do it better (in the json reading part):

- reading each file in a different `ptree`
- reading each file in the same `ptree`
- reading each file in the same `ptree`, but clear each time the `ptree`

I do this in the constructor of a class that has a member of type `ptree` and I would not create another 3 `ptree`s if not needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Having a local ptree for case 3 doesn't fit what you want ?

Comment: It fits, but shall I do `clear()` or not?

Comment: read_json doc specifies ptree is cleared so it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way is to do case 2 with a local ptree to populate the class member ptree. Note that case 2 and 3 are actually the same because, [as specified in the doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/json_parser/read_json_id1147617.html), the ptree instance is cleared.